# New blog template to display only one category

Tags: posts, categories, themes

I understand that I can copy my theme's default blog template and change the code to make it display only posts from one category in the theme's style. I tried tinkering with it, but to no result yet. This is the code in the theme:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'post', 'paged'=>$paged) );
            if( $posts->have_posts() ):
                echo '<div class="list-posts">';
                while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                endwhile;
                echo '</div>';

                wp_reset_postdata();
            else:
                echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.esc_html__('Sorry. There are no posts to display', 'gon').'</div>';
            endif;
```

I tried changing the values on `while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();`  but to no success.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is creating a new query for the main page loop it is doing something very wrong. To get a category archive, all you should need is a template named [according to one of these patterns](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category), depending on your need:

1. `category-{slug}.php` – If the category’s slug is `news`, WordPress will look for `category-news.php`.
2. `category-{id}.php` – If the category’s ID is `6`, WordPress will look for `category-6.php`.
3. `category.php`

With a Loop in it that looks like this:

```
if( have_posts() ) {
  echo '<div class="list-posts">';
  while( have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
  }
  echo '</div>';
  wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
  echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.esc_html__('Sorry. There are no posts to display', 'gon').'</div>';
}
```

Plus, of course, whatever code your theme needs surrounding that. I can't really guess what that code looks like.